# replace but except in anchor text

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to replace a string in a html text but except if it is within hyperlink tags (anchor text).

For example:

```
The name of my dog is Mike. I always <a href="....">walk with my dog here</a>.
```

Than replace *dog* with *cat*, but not the the dog in the anchor text. So the result should be:

```
The name of my cat is Mike. I always <a href="....">walk with my dog here</a>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only select "dog" when it's not between `>` and `</a>`.

`(dog)+(?![^>]*\</a>)`